# Migrate DB2 LUW 9.7 databases and data to PostgreSQL

Tags: database-migration, postgresql-9.3, db2-luw

I am trying to migrate DB2 LUW 9.7 databases and data to PostgreSQL 9.3. Any suggestion on which will be the best approach to do it? Which will be the best tool or any open source tool available to perform this?

Answer (score 1):

The [db2look](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002051.html) utility can reverse-engineer your DB2 tables into DDL statements that will serve as a good starting point for your PostgreSQL definitions. To unload the data from each table, use the [EXPORT](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008303.html) command, which dumps the results of any SQL SELECT to a delimited text file. Although the [db2move](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002079.html) utility can handle both of those tasks, is not going to be of much help to you because it extracts the table data into IBM's proprietary PC/IXF format.

If you're moving off of DB2 because of price, IBM provides a free-as-in-beer version called [DB2 Express-C](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/express-c/), which shares the same core database engine as paid editions of DB2. Express-C is a first-rate, industrial strength DBMS that does not have the sort of severe limitations that other commercial vendors impose on their no-cost engines.